# Sustitución de valores en R

Tags: r

Tengo un data.frame

```
datos<-c("PV1","PV2","PV3","PV4","PV5")
colnames<-c("PV")
```

y me gustaría sustituir el valor PV por "3.", de tal forma que me quede algo así:

```
Datos:     PV
          3.1
          3.2
          3.3
          3.4
          3.5
```

¿Cómo puedo sustituir dicho valor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza [`sub()`](http://rfunction.com/archives/2354) (o `gsub()` si hay más de una sustitución por elemento):

```
sub("PV", "3.", datos)
```

Esto sustituye "PV" por "3.".

Si después ejecutas `print(datos)` verás que todos los elementos han sido modificados.

Si por el contrario lo que buscas es generar un patrón incremental sobre la variable, puedes generarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
datos <- paste0('3.',seq(datos))
```

Con `seq(datos)` generamos una secuencia de 1 a la longitud del vector `datos` y con `paste0` concatenamos y construimos el nuevo patrón.